# Drop-down value selection for ul li block using pageFactory

Tags: html, selenium

Issue - I have a dropdown menu with ul and li tags. For that i have identified the xpath and its working. Now in dropdown i have 6 options to select. If i directly use below code its working.

```
String value = "Showcase";
WebElement dropdown = 
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Resources')]"));
dropdown.click(); 
// assuming you have to click the "dropdown" to open it
dropdown.findElement(By.xpath("(//a[contains(text(),'Showcase')])[1]")).click();
```

But i want to use it in POM (Page Factory). Can anyone help me in this.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SjodA.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

If you are tying to use POM, firstly add Page Factory initialisation to your class where methods are. It is as follows:

```
public RandomPO(){
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this); }
```

Then try selecting a value using Select method (hopefully dropdown is created with select method):

```
Select selectItem= new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("pathToAnElement")));
selectItem.selectByValue("Your value");
```

And change "Your value" with text value of dropdown item (literally if you want to select lets say "10 minutes" , you put "10 minutes".

Comment: dropdown is not created with select method. That.s the problem am facing. Attached image is html block with ul and li